# Unable to update/install Jenkins plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Hi I'm not able to Update/Install any plugins in Jenkins getting this error below.

```
Branch API  Failure -

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/branch-api/2.5.6/branch-api.hpi
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:3000)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
Caused: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/branch- 
api/2.5.6/branch-api.hpi
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at 
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1938)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1139)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/branch-api/2.5.6/branch-api.hpi to /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/branch-api.jpi.tmp
```

Also when I try Check Now in manage plugin -> advance getting this error:

```
A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.
Stack trace
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your update site is wrong; https://updates.jenkins.io/. Fix under `/pluginManager/advanced`.

Also, 2.5.6 is still several years and releases obsolete, as is most likely your Jenkins instance itself.

---

As for the JDK issue, what is your JDK installation? Most likely, Java installation used by your Jenkins does not recognize the SSL certificates that Let's Encrypt provides for the Jenkins update center. There are hundreds of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore?noredirect=1&lq=1) here and on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1400728/jenkins-plugins-install-issue) to the PKIX certificate problem.

You'll have to figure out the situation specific scenario, but should be fine with the latest AdoptOpenJDK implementations: [Temurin - hotpsot](https://adoptium.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot) , [Semeru - OpenJ9](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/downloads).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried with your suggestion but still no luck.
I have upgraded Jenkins 2.303.3 and updated JDK 11 but error is still there.
There were errors checking the update sites: SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

This is not allowing to update and install plugins.

Comment: Added JDK response